# How to work with if not in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to print the `div` with the class called `inner-content-div`, if the variable `$name` is not consisted with the following strings.

- Gingelly Rolls
- Kithul Treacle
- Coconut Vinegar

But my PHP code is not working.

Here is my code.

```
<?php
  $vid = explode("/", $_GET["q"]);
  $name = taxonomy_term_load($vid[2]);
?>

<h1 id="page-title" class="title"><?php print $name->name; ?></h1>

<?php 
  $exclude_list = array("Gingelly Rolls","Kithul Treacle","Coconut Vinegar");
  if(!in_array($name, $exclude_list)){       ?>
    <div class="inner-content-div">
       <!-- Here are some HTML code.-->
    </div>
<?php 
  } 
?>
```

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: What on earth are you talking about?

Comment: What does `$name` look like?

Comment: what `$name` contains? try to echo it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try like this. First print `$vid[2]`, using `echo $vid[2];`. Then put `$vid[2]` values into the array called `$exclude_list`. Then use the following code.

```
$exclude_list = array(//value 1, value 2, value 3);
if(!in_array($vid[2], $exclude_list)) {
   //Your HTML code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be -

```
if(!in_array($name->name, $exclude_list)){
```

as you are printing it -

```
<h1 id="page-title" class="title"><?php print $name->name; ?></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $vid = explode("/", $_GET["q"]);
  $name = taxonomy_term_load($vid[2]);
  $exclude_list = array("Gingelly Rolls","Kithul Treacle","Coconut Vinegar");
?>

<h1 id="page-title" class="title"><?php echo $name->name; ?></h1>

<?php if(!in_array($name->name, $exclude_list)): ?>
    <div class="inner-content-div">
       <!-- Here are some HTML code.-->
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It could be because `$name` is an object. Also, probably better to use PHP's alternate syntax for cleaner html/templates.

The other potential issue here is that the casing of the items in the exclude list could potentially not match the value of name. You should probably normalize those to all lower case when doing the comparison.